# Entity Framework Code First from database not adding Key attribute

Tags: entity-framework, attributes, ef-code-first, primary-key, data-annotations

When generating code first classes from an existing database the KeyAttribute is not added to the property of primary key of the table.

All tables from the database have a single column int PK named Id, there are no composite keys

A form generator and other classes use this attribute via reflection for internal logic

**Can I configure Entity Framework to add the KeyAttribute to primary key properties when regenerating the model classes?**

or

**I'll have to manually annotate all key properties via the MetadataType attribute and change my code to support metadata types?**

Thanks

Comment: By which tool do you generate code?

Comment: with visual studio, using the ado.net entity data model add new item dialog, selecting the 'code first from database' option

Comment: So does it generate fluent mappings? (contrary to former EF Tools it doesn't afaik).

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio code first wizard generate fluent mappings, **but** the HasKey method is never called, which is the primary key mapping method

Comment: Weird. Do your tables really have primary keys (not just unique indexes)?

Comment: yes, on sql server manager the columns appear with PK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80231/discussion-between-rafael-and-gert-arnold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. See the snippet from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx below.

`One of the conventions that code first depends on is how it implies which property is the key in each of the code first classes. That convention is to look for a property named “Id”...`

Meaning if you name your pk Id it will infer that Id is the pk.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not name primary key columns as 'Id'**

For some reason, when the column name its 'Id', the Key attribute is not added by the code first from existing database wizard

This was the code generated with 'Id' column:

```
[Table("tabla")]
public partial class tabla
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

This was the code generated with just renaming 'Id' to 'llave'

```
[Table("tabla")]
public partial class tabla
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int llave { get; set; }
```